# Change Code Behind code in existing sharepoint farm solution

Tags: sharepoint-designer, codebehind

I am new to Sharepoint. I am using Sharepoint designer 2013. There is an existing ASP.NET application hosted in IIS. I am able to find **Login.aspx** in **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\customLoginPage** path. But how to locate it's corresponding Login.aspx.cs file?

I know we don't host .cs file. We register it in **GAC**. But I want to take this file on my local machine, make some changes and re-host the application. How can I do it? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the source code (which will include both the aspx and cs files). The server will have the compiled version which you will not be able to modify. If you've lost the source code, you can use a tool like .NET Reflector or similar to decompile it, but it will not be a one-to-one match between the original source code and the decompiled source code.

Comment: Thanks. Yahh. I know I can use Reflector but this is not the ideal way. I am new to the project and not able to find source code.

Comment: Then you're stuck in that case. You've only got access to compiled code which isn't editable, of course.